# What are the main safety threats to be aware of in South Africa as a tourist?

Tags: safety, security, south-africa

I have been looking in to arranging a short backpacking trip  around South Africa later this year. From what I have read both on the internet and in travel guides, and talking to South Africans it's making me think twice, it's giving me the impression that it seems  almost certain I will be involved in some sort of incident, which I hope is not the case.

What are likely to be the main safety threats on a three week holiday, flying into Cape Town and out of Nelspruit (via Johannesburg). We will be travelling internally by foot, hire car, and 2 internal flights (George to Durban, and Durban to Nelspruit).

Comment: A bit of a subjective question, but as a South African/New Zealand citizen, if you've been to 6 continents, you'll have the experience to reduce your risk a lot.  I took 4 friends there in 2005 for a month and the only problem was a robbery in Soweto...and it was a beginner's mistake from a couple of them.  But you can't guarantee anything obviously.  You'll learn on the ground, and talking to other travellers as you go will let you know what to do or not do as well.

Comment: Certainly not 'almost certain' to be involved in an incident.

Comment: I have edited. Am is the question up to standard yet?